# Sql entries disappear and appear despite being in range

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Screenshot]

As seen in the screenshot, the entries for July 21st and 22nd are **not** returned in the first query, but are returned in the second query, despite the entries being in range for both.

I know there are some gaps in other places, but that's because there's actually no data for those days. July 21st and 22nd however do have data. In one query they are shown, in the other they are not despite being in the range both times. The ownerID is the same in both cases.

I am completely lost.

---

cha's comment is correct. This would be the correct query:

```
SELECT SUM( amount ) ,  `date` 
FROM  `yp_corpWalletJournal` 
WHERE ownerID =xxx
AND refTypeID =85
AND  `date` >=  '2014-06-23'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(  `date` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
ORDER BY  `yp_corpWalletJournal`.`DATE` DESC
```

Comment: when you are grouping by DAY(date) you are grouping the days from different months together, i.e 21st of June and 21st of July are grouped into one. Your result is completely unpredictable

Comment: Oh man, that's right. One of those brainfart moments. Thank you very much, cha!

Comment: @Hijacker you probably want to include the same DATE_FORMAT('date', '%y-%m-%d') in the SELECT as well seeing as the time is not important.

Answer (score 1):

This might be triggered because of the grouping by only the day part of the date.

Try using `GROUP BY date` instead of using `GROUP BY DAY(date)`

Comment: Well, the second query specifies "bigger than June 23rd", so naturally the June 21st and June 22nd entries would disappear.
Grouping only by date will result in 6000 lines, since the date field includes the time. It would essentially defy the use of GROUP BY in that case.

Comment: @Mariano is correct in that the GROUP BY DAY(date) is the problem - because this just returns the day of the month. The 'date' returned in the SELECT is just one arbitrary date from within that GROUP - ie could be from June or July.